# How to pass the data obtained from the PHP page on the server's local page in JS?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML 5 page that you can use offline.
When this page is online you should connect to a PHP page (the 'I've already done) with a login and receive response in 1 string and 2 integers.

How to pass the data obtained from the PHP page on the server's local page in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is what you need to use to establish communication between PHP and JS. To make this simple, take a look to the Jquery AJAX documentation. If you want PHP to return your response serialized, then you'll need to use json_encode( )

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass data from PHP to Javascript, you must use something like an [AJAX call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to the PHP file. The response will then be whatever the PHP returns, and you can handle it with Javascript.